# Wait for two parallel requests (each can fail) and continue execution

Tags: angular

I want to send two GET requests in PARALLEL (this is important) to get `user` and `project` and then when I have both, I want send third request to check that I have access or not and then load buildings and make further processing - as follows

```js
forkJoin([
    this.myService.getProject(projectId),  // gives observable
    this.myService.getUser(userId),        // gives observable
]).subscribe(async result => {
    this.project =result[0];
    this.user = result[1];

    //AT THIS POINT I would like to have this.project/user=null if request fail

    if(this.user && this.project) {
        let access = this.myService.hasAccess(this.project, this.user).toPromise()
        this.showAccess(access);
    } else {
        this.showWarning();
    } 

    this.buildings = this.myService.getBuildings().toPromise();

    if (this.user) { ... }    // further processing
    if (this.project) { ... } // further processing
});
```

But there is following problem: if `getProject` or `getUser` request fail then code in subscribe section newer will be executed (e.g. `getBuildings` request will be newer send) - I just want to ALWAYS execute code in this subscribe body - in case when getProject fails I just want to have this.project=null (same with user).

**Question**: How to do it?

Comment: You need to `pipe` to `catchError` on both of the observables you pass to `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [catch](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) the errors and map them to `null`

```js
forkJoin([
  this.myService.getProject(projectId).pipe(
    catchError(() => of(null))
  ),
  this.myService.getUser(userId).pipe(
    catchError(() => of(null))
  ),
])
```